# How to move all data in rows to one column using Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

How do I move all data in rows to one column using Notepad++? For example, if I start with

```
1 2 4  
4 5 6  
7 8 9
```

How do I move the data so that I end up with

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming numbers are separated by horizontal spaces:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h+`
- Replace with: `\n`    # or `\r\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]